# How to find cause of PHP notices with no stack trace?

Tags: php

My WordPress debug.log is filling up with this group of seven PHP warnings/notices, recurring at least every half an hour...

```
[08-Mar-2018 09:05:03 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/mysite/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php on line 3736
[08-Mar-2018 09:05:03 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/mysite/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php on line 3738
[08-Mar-2018 09:05:03 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/mysite/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php on line 3740
[08-Mar-2018 09:05:03 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/mysite/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php on line 3736
[08-Mar-2018 09:05:03 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/mysite/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php on line 3738
[08-Mar-2018 09:05:03 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/mysite/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php on line 3740
[08-Mar-2018 09:05:03 UTC] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/mysite/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php:3736) in /home/mysite/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1216
```

The trouble is, as far as I can see, there is no reference to which plugin or culprit is causing this (I think the term for this is, there is no back trace / stack trace), so I'm finding it hard to debug.

The question is: **How can I find out more detail in order to trace the cause?**

I already have `WP_DEBUG`, `WP_DEBUG` and `WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY` all set to true.

I have looked in to setting PHP `display_errors` and `error_reporting` but, since I am already getting notices and warnings output, I am not sure whether these settings would add any more detail.

Is it possible these warnings are being generated by a non-WordPress plugin? I do have a PHP script operating on cron which invokes the wpdb environment but which is not strictly a plugin.

Comment: The best way would be to use a debugger like [xdebug](https://xdebug.org/) but a fast and easy way could be to add the line `error_log(print_r(debug_backtrace(), true));` at the plae where the notice appears. With this you manually add a stack trace to the error log.

Comment: @ahendwh2 Thanks, 1) I looked in to xedebug but it requires a new version of PHP than I have. 2) "At the place where the notice appears" - where is this? I mean, if I knew where it appeared, I'd know more. Output refs `class-wp-query.php` and `pluggable.php`, but I wouldn't know where to place the debug line outside of these. The plugin I most want to test has no front-end.

Comment: You should place the debug line in `class-wp-query.php` right after (or before) line 3736

Comment: Okay, adding `error_log(print_r(debug_backtrace(), true));` to `class-wp-query.php` (whether before or after line 3736) adds several 999-line entries to debug.log, spitting out an array (and arrays within arrays). It all seems to correlate with page ID 2, which is my homepage. But I don't know what I'm looking for; it doesn't seem to state any errors. It didn't really add a more detailed stack trace as I understand it, just the arrays.

Comment: Hmm. Have you tried to deactivate one plugin after another and see, wether the error persists?

Comment: @RobertAndrews Have you seen my answer? Does it work for you?

Answer (score 11):

You can get the backtrace by trapping the E_NOTICE message. If you add the following snippet to wp-config.php just before

```
/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */
```

you should see the full backtrace in the error log.

```
set_error_handler(function() {
    error_log(print_r(debug_backtrace(), true));
    return true;
}, E_USER_NOTICE);

define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */
```

PS: Returning `true` at the end of the function tells PHP to stop processing the E_NOTICE, which is probably what you want at this point.

I *just* used this approach on a project and it was exactly the solution I was looking for. In fact, I found this post while looking for a way to do the same thing. Happy sailing!

Comment: I earlier installed and enabled xdebug to uncover more detail. I'm currently unable to test whether your answer works, though it looks like a great solution to use in lieu of xdebug.

Comment: Xdebug is always the best solution but this does work for me. If you do get a chance to test it and it does solve your problem it would be great if you could select it as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Certainly will.

Answer (score 3):

Ted's answer worked great for me, but was super verbose, making it both hard to read and easy to accidentally create a massive log file if you left it on accidentally.

I ended up using this for a more concise log entry:

```
set_error_handler(function() {
    $log = "\r\n==========\r\nSTACK TRACE:";
    foreach ( debug_backtrace() as $i => $item ) {
        if ( 0 === $i ) {
            $log .= "\r\n" . $item['args'][1];
        } else {
            $log .= "\r\n" . $item['file'] . ' -- line ' . $item['line'];
        }
    }
    $log .= "\r\n==========";
    error_log( $log );
    return true;
}, E_USER_NOTICE);

define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
```

This cut the particular error I was looking at down from 13,000 lines in my log file to around 20, and allowed me to quickly identify which plugin was the culprit.